# Lightswitch Html - How to Disable Auto-Refresh Parameterized Query?

Tags: html, visual-studio-lightswitch

I have a Lightswitch Html screen based on a parameterized query with multiple parameters.  My desired behavior is to allow the user to change multiple search fields and then tap a button to refresh the screen.  The default lightswitch behavior is to refresh on change of any parameter which causes multiple unnecessary calls to the server in my use case.

Is there a way to disable the auto refresh and call the query_execute as needed?

Answer (score 1):

I've only done this for Silverlight clients, but it may well be the same for HTML clients.

In the screen designer, highlight the query on the left. In it's properties panel, there will be a check box for "Auto Execute Query." Clear that check box.

Now the query won't load until you explicitly tell it to in code. in C# this looks like

```
this.queryName.Load();
```

and can be triggered from a button, keystroke, etc.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  For whatever reason, "Auto Exec Query" isn't present in the Query properties of the html client.  http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/8ba5bc5f-b3fe-44d3-a7e8-67d924b7772d/html-client-autoexecute-query